# Doctrine 2 fetch="EAGER"

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

In Doctrine you could set a fetch mode in your entities to fetch all data by one query and not lazy load all of them.

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Categorie" , fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="CAT_ID", referencedColumnName="CAT_ID")
 * @access protected
 * @var \Application\Entity\Categorie
 */
protected $CAT_ID;
```

I have problems with this when it comes to a 3rd level.
Entity "a" has a relation to entity "b". Entity "b" has a relation to entity "c". Entity "a" and entity "b" are selected in one query and entity "c" is separated from them in a single query. I´ve set `fetch="EAGER"` on every relation between them.

Doesnt Doctrine handle `fetch="EAGER"` in a 3rd level or what is going wrong?

Answer (score 14):

I don't think so, but what you can do is set EAGER mode only when neccessary

```
<?php
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT u FROM MyProject\User u");
$query->setFetchMode("MyProject\User", "address", \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata::FETCH_EAGER);
$query->execute();
```

For more information turn to [Doctrine docs](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#temporarily-change-fetch-mode-in-dql).